# AngularJS Infinite scroll calls function even on scrolling up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, infinite-scroll

I am using infinite scroll from http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll v1.1.0. 
I have a table whose contents will be loaded dynamically as the user scrolls down.

I did the same thing in this  [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cw63FvFjFlAWMdHmx1ZJ?p=preview) which pushes data inside the array which is displayed inside a div and it works fine as expected.

When I tried to do the same on other page, showMore() function is called not only on scrolling down but also when scrolling up. 
Here the structure of the table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Some heading</th>       
            <th>Some other heading</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <div infinite-scroll="showMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="3" infinite-scroll-disabled='infiniteScrollDisabled'>
        <tr ng-repeat="r in report">
            <td>{{$index}}</td>    
            <td">{{r.someData}}</td>
        </tr>
      </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I dont understand why `showMore()` function is called even on scrolling up. Has it anything to do with the table structure ?

Comment: First of all, what a `div` is doing in the `tbody` and wrapping a `tr`? This is invalid `HTML` markup.

Comment: Fixed it, now the div is outside table tag,something like this
`<div infinite-scroll="showMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="3" infinite-scroll-disabled='infiniteScrollDisabled'>... 
  <table>...
  </table>
</div>`

Still calling `showMore()` function on scrolling up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to move
`<div infinite-scroll="showMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="3" infinite-scroll-disabled='infiniteScrollDisabled'>`

outside the `<table>.....</table>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

I found this issue on github and it solved it for me
https://github.com/sroze/ngInfiniteScroll/issues/157

```
<div class="constrained" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <table infinite-scroll="increaseLimit()" infinite-scroll-container='".constrained"'>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:barLimit">
            <td>Number</td>
            <td>{{item.number}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

credit: BenjaminWFox

This jsFiddle demonstrates this (along with filtering etc) https://jsfiddle.net/lisapfisterer/Lu4sbxps/